# what is the -b option in systemctl StartExec command line

Tags: ubuntu, systemctl

Looking at Miguel Grinberg explanation on how to start a FlaskApp with systemctl.
https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/running-a-flask-application-as-a-service-with-systemd

He shows:
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/microblog/venv/bin/gunicorn -b localhost:8000 -w 4 microblog:app

I cannot find a list of options for ExecStart or systemctl anywhere.

What is the -b option?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-b` option is actually for `gunicorn` in this case.  It is for the bind address.

From the docs:

> -b BIND, --bind=BIND - Specify a server socket to bind. Server sockets can be any of $(HOST), $(HOST):$(PORT), fd://$(FD), or unix:$(PATH). An IP is a valid $(HOST).

Reference: https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/run.html

Comment: No wonder I couldn't figure it out. Thanks. Since I only have 12 reputation points, my up-vote is not displayed. I'll come back later and fix that.